# ConTeXt: How to suppress indentation after setup

Tags: indentation, context

Let's say I have a setuo foo, and I always want to suppress indentation for the next paragraph? Is there a way to achieve this?

```
\startsetups foo
    FOO
\stopsetups

\setupindenting[yes,medium,next]

\starttext

First paragraph. Not indented.

This paragraph should be indented.

\directsetup{foo}

This paragraph should not be indented.

\stoptext
```

Comment: Before the paragraph, that should not have an indent, wirte \noindent.
This should be it.

Comment: Indeed, but I am looking for an automatic solution. Something like `indentnext=no`.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282559/i-want-to-set-first-paragraph-of-text-environment-to-no-indentation but I have not tested if it will work with context

Comment: No. Not a duplicate. The linked question is about indentation in environments, mine is about indentation after a setup. Besides, the solution both apply only to LaTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
\startsetups foo
    FOO
    \noindentation
\stopsetups

\setupindenting[yes,medium,next]

\starttext

First paragraph. Not indented.

This paragraph should be indented.

\directsetup{foo}

This paragraph should not be indented.

This paragraph should be indented.

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: It works. Too easy -- I was looking for something more complicated. I should have tried that before asking the question, but I didn't expect this to work (just like `\noindent` would not have worked for this in LaTeX.) Let's hope this is a feature and stays...